# Methods of Creating Higher Levels of Entropy in a Seed

Tags: java, c++, c, random, entropy

For fun I have been experimenting with methods of encryption. One of the methods I am using requires a seed value. I would like to feed it with true random numbers. I know a standard method of acquiring a seed in for example C++ is to call time(NULL), however since this is only pseudo-random I was wondering if there are any reliable ways of gathering truly random numbers. The only constraint is that it must be possible to implement in C, C++, and Java.

Thank you in advance.

Clarification: While I run Ubuntu, this code must run a Windows system.

Comment: It depends on what you need it for and your platform. For one time entropy generation (password generation) getting random mouse movements from the user is a popular method. If you are on linux you could simply read from `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`. It really depends on what exactly you need your seeds for and where you are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of them, but you've got your terminology confused, because *any* source of entropy bits will be a random number generator.  You're actually thinking about "pseudorandom numbers".

Now, that said, there are a number of different schemes for entropy sources.  A lot of UNIX-like systems have a /dev/random which creates random numbers by doing various magic on physical processes like cache sizes and memory contents.  There are stronger sources that use, for example, inter-event times with radioactive decay.

Fourmilab.ch provides real random numbers [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/).

CCDs kept in the dark [work well](http://www.lavarnd.org/what/index.html).

[Lava lamps](http://www.lavarnd.org/news/lavadiff.html) are nice.

Comment: I think the edit's wrong, though -- you want to seed it with real random numbers, and you want a scheme that's not dependent on some other pseudorandom number generator.  Arguably, /dev/random is only pseudorandom, and actually time(NULL) isn't very random at all, since it autocorrelates badly -- two times in seconds, taken 100 seconds apart, will differ only in the lowest two digits.

Comment: So how would you word this question? Sorry if im a bit slow, this is a new field to me

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your system, you may have access to a source of truly random data. For example, `/dev/random` in Linux will give you a cryptographically strong source of random bits. It's usually slow, so using it to seed a PRNG is a good way to use it when you don't really need true randomness.

Answer (score 1):

Some magic with [high-resolution performance counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Stamp_Counter) is, probably, going to give a good seed. Especially, if you consider, multi-core system, different CPU loads etc.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to implement this in for example java?

Comment: They give you examples on how to use `RTDSC` in several languages there. And then you do appropriate manipulation with value (bitwise shift etc).

Answer (score 0):

As **Charlie Martin** mentions, a good source of truly random numbers is from cameras (video or still). If you use the least significant bit of pixels from a digital camera and concatenate them in a string of the required length, you will have an excellent random number generator.

Comment: It's reasonably good, but there does tend to be some banding which becomes autocorrelation.  The link to Landon's LavaRnd site (the second link in my answer) explains what he does to reduce the effect.